# pythonのDjangoでのmigration

Tags: python, python3, django

pythonのDjangoを使用して、Webアプリケーションを作りたいと思っています。
現在は、初期設定を行なっています。
ですが、下記のようにそのようなモジュール名のファイルはありませんと記載されてしまい、
どのようにすればマイグレーションできるのかわかりません。

```
＄ python manage.py migrate
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
  from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

Djangoはインストールできています。

```
$ pip freeze
Django==1.8
```

インターネットで検索をして似たような内容はあるのですが、
具体的な操作の回答はなかったので、教えていただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こちらの件ですが、pythonのバージョンが古くて表示されたエラーでした。
http://graphbooth.com/2017/05/31/pythonmac.html

上記のサイトを見ながら解決させていただきました。
djangoのバージョンとphthonのバージョンが合っていなかったようです。
お答えくださった方すみません。

Answer (score 0):

もしかして、 `django` というディレクトリを作りませんでしたか？（django-adminのstartprojectでdjangoという名前を付けた、等）。そうれあれば、別の名前を付けてください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
djangoというディレクトリは作成しておりません。